# Importing model formulas to a .cto Hyperledger composer model

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am playing around with the developer tutorials on how to build a blockchain based business network using Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Composer, and I am curious about where to place mathematical formulas. Do these go in the chain-code, or is there any way to import a namespace to the .cto file containing formulas?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use mathematical formulas in logic.js file.

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

The `.cto` file define the domain model for a business network definition.

The logic file define the actual logic behind your business network, i.e. your chaincode.

So, if you are using Hyperledge Composer, you can use Mathematical Formula in `logic.js` file.

There is also go and java SDK available to write chaincode.